# How can I make an HtmlTextWriter object use spaces instead of tabs for its Indents?

Tags: c#, html, .net, htmltextwriter

I am creating some html from code running on a WinForm. I want to create the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>foo</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter class to do this like so:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter();
htmlWriter.WriteFullBeginTag("html");
htmlWriter.WriteLine();
htmlWriter.WriteFullBeginTag("body");
htmlWriter.WriteLine();
htmlWriter.Indent++;
htmlWriter.WriteFullBeginTag("div");
htmlWriter.WriteLine();
htmlWriter.Indent++;
htmlWriter.WriteFullBeginTag("p");
htmlWriter.Write("foo");
htmlWriter.WriteEndTag("p");
htmlWriter.Indent--;
htmlWriter.WriteLine();
htmlWriter.WriteEndTag("div");    
htmlWriter.Indent--;
htmlWriter.WriteLine();
htmlWriter.WriteEndTag("body");
htmlWriter.WriteLine();
htmlWriter.WriteEndTag("html");
```

This works just fine, however, when I open the resulting html in a text editor my indentation just looks way too far to me, since it is using tab chars. Is there a way to force this class to use a number of spaces instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a System.Web.UI guy, but from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8y8wst5(VS.80).aspx), it looks like you can supply the character to use for indentation as the second argument to the HtmlTextWriter constructor. Thus, to get 4 spaces instead of a tab:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = 
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(yourTextWriter, "    ");
```

Comment: Wow... I feel like a mouth breather. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

David has technically answered your question, but that path leads to the dark side.  Client-side web code is not compiled.  If you use four spaces instead of a tab character, you're doing it wrong.

Even if the impact is small, when is it acceptable to be 400% less efficient?  If you want to make things a tiny bit slower for no good reason, you could also randomly add Thread.Sleep() calls to your server-side code.

Fix your text editor's settings.